# Append Date as a variable name in Fail2Ban

Tags: security, variables, date

I need to append date as my logfile name contains date at the end.
e.g :

```
access_log.2013-12-11
access_log.2013-12-10
access_log.2013-12-09
access_log.2013-12-08
.
.
.
access_log.2013-09-08
```

AsI need to set logpath name under Fail2ban conf file (i.e jail.local)

I am aware that I can use '*' while mentioning log file name but as our log files are large and we also store 30 days worth of log files, so I thought it is not a good practice and will also performance related effects.

```
logpath = /opt/atlassian/jira/logs/access_log.*
```

Tested the below one's :

```
logpath = /opt/atlassian/jira/logs/access_log.%Y-%m-%d
logpath = "/opt/atlassian/jira/logs/access_log.%Y-%m-%d"
logpath = "/opt/atlassian/jira/logs/access_log.'%Y-%m-%d'"
```

but none have worked

Can anyone please help me in appending a variable date at the end of logpath to cover the above mentioned log files

Comment: I dont know much about if there is anything specific to Fail2Ban, if you are looking for a pythonic solution 

new_name = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('{}.%Y-%m-%d').format(fname)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are getting your dates, but this will create a logpath in the format you desire

```
import datetime
d = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
logpath = "/opt/atlassian/jira/logs/access_log/%s" %d
print logpath
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...
but looks like as it is a config file it is not allowing me to add/run these lines
errors :
ERROR  Failed during configuration: File contains no section headers.
file: /etc/fail2ban/jail.local, line: 1
'import datetime\n'
fail2ban-client reload
ERROR  Failed during configuration: File contains no section headers.
file: /etc/fail2ban/jail.local, line: 1
"d = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')\n"

Comment: What I wrote above was python. Presumably there is some sort of regex allowed in the config files. If that won't work, you could have a python script running as a daily cron job that writes the config file with the log files of the last 30 days.

Comment: Ok Thanks.... Having '*' on logpath and running unix cron jobs to purge logs or Pointing to a unique file whereas cron job runs everyday to create a softlink with today's date are my backup options.
but I was looking if anyone could help me by providing a better standard solution.